# PDO FETCH_INTO Factory?

Tags: php, pdo, factory

I have a factory called `ProductFactory`

I can create a product like so:

```
$product = ProductFactory::getProduct($id);
```

Now depending on what type of product we are getting, this function may return a class of type `Product` or a descendant or `Product`.

But using the method above, the `$product` class would be responsible for connecting to the database and retrieving its data.

---

So if I were to select 20 products to be displayed on a category list, I would have to first get a list of all the ID's then call the above function 20 times. This would be 21 calls to the database.

So I added another function to my factory like so:

```
$product = ProductFactory::createProduct($data);
```

This does the same thing, except you pass in the data from the database, saving the `$product` class from having to make the trip. (depending on what data you pass, the factory will return the right type of class).

So now I want to make one call to select all products data and `FETCH_INTO` my factory to generate a $product object for each row.

How can I do that?

### update

Here is what I tried that did not work:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO,ProductFactory::createProduct);
foreach($stmt as $product)
{
    echo get_class($product) . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the last part: what you want to do? Specifically, which part of your question isn't answered by http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use [PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE](http://docs.php.net/pdo.constants) for something like

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
initDemo($pdo);

$result = $pdo->query("SELECT IF(x,'Product','ProductXVal'), id, x FROM soTest");
while ( $obj=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE) ) {
  echo get_class($obj), "\n";
}

class Product {
  public function id() { return $this->id; }
}

class ProductXVal extends Product {
  public function x() { return $this->x; }
}

function initDemo($pdo) {
  $pdo->exec('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soTest (id int auto_increment, x int, primary key(id))');
  $pdo->exec('INSERT INTO soTest (x) VALUES (1),(NULL),(2),(NULL),(3),(NULL)');
}
```

which prints

```
Product
ProductXVal
Product
ProductXVal
Product
ProductXVal
```

but that seems rather ...odd to say the least.
I'd rather fetch the data as an array and then pass it to a factory that creates the appropriate object. You could do so in a class derived from PDO and/or PDOStatement.

Comment: I think I will just do what you recommend at the end.. `fetch the data as an array and then pass it to a factory` ..Seems the most strait forward.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the comments section on the PDOStatement->fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#usernotes) page, you should do this:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, new myClass());
$stmt->execute();
while ($object = $stmt->fetch())
{
  $result[] = clone $object;
}
```

So differences there are

1. You're passing fetch_into a method rather than an existing object
2. You're not executing the statement (in your example, at least)
3. You didn't include a call to fetch() in your loop
4. You're not cloning the object

Now I don't know if it'll work with a factory method instead of an existing object, but calling execute() and fetch() is the least you can do :)

Comment: Does calling foreach() over a statement execute it? I'd never noticed PDOStatement implements Traversable...

Comment: No and yes, execute() executes the statement and it implements Traversable ;-)